# Calculating SHA-1 hashes in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, hash, sha1

## Calculating SHA-1 hashes in Java and C#

I'm trying to replicate the logic of a Java application within a C# application.  Part of this involves generating an SHA-1 hash of a password.  Unfortunately I can't get the same results from Java and C#.

```
C# Output  : 64  0a  b2 ba e0 7b  ed c4 c1 63  f6 79  a7 46  f7 ab 7f  b5 d1 fa
Java Output: 164 10a b2 ba e0 17b ed c4 c1 163 f6 179 a7 146 f7 ab 17f b5 d1 fa
```

To try and figure out what is happening I've been using the Debugger in Eclipse and Visual Studio.

```
1. Check values of byte[] key:

    Java: { 84, 101, 115, 116 }
    C#  : { 84, 101, 115, 116 }

2. Check value of byte[] hash:

    Java: { 100 10 -78 -70 -32 123 ... }
    C#  : { 100 10  78 186 224 123 ... }
```

I've read the other posts on this topic, which largely refer to input string encoding, but these don't seem to have helped me.  My guess would be that this is something to do with signed vs. unsigned bytes but I'm not making much progress down this track.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Karle

---

### Java Version:

```
public void testHash() {

    String password = "Test";

    byte[] key = password.getBytes();

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

    byte[] hash = md.digest(key);

    String result = "";
    for ( byte b : hash ) {
        result += Integer.toHexString(b + 256) + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

### C# Version:

```
public void testHash() {

    String password = "Test";

    byte[] key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);

    SHA1 sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();

    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(key);

    String result;
    foreach ( byte b in hash ) {
        result += Convert.ToInt32(b).ToString("x2") + " ";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);

}
```

Comment: Your output routine is different. In the Java code you add 256 to the byte value, in C+ you don't... as 256 dec == 100 hex, this is exactly the difference you are observing: `64` <-> `164`

Comment: Java bytes are signed, C# bytes are unsigned.  A Java `byte` is equivalent to a C# `sbyte`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Java version, do not use `b + 256`; instead, use `b & 255`. The SHA-1 part is fine, this is just a matter of printing the output. Java's "`byte`" type is signed: it returns values between -128 and 127. To get the corresponding unsigned value, you must add 256 *only if* the value is negative.

A bitwise AND with 255 (that's what "`& 255`" does) operates the proper conversion, which, at the binary level, is truncation of the value to its 8 least significant bits.

Comment: I guess I should have realised that values like "163" in HEX were clearly above the highest value for a byte.  I made the change you suggested and now get the correct result.  Thanks, Karle

Answer (score 0):

your question and the answer were very useful to me, but I noticed that when the password has the character "0" hash codes generated are different, so I changed a little the code (in Java).

```
for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++)
    {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(hash[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) hex = "0" + hex;
        hex = hex.substring(hex.length() - 2);
        result += hex;
    }
```