# SHA1 hash computation not returing same result for java and c#

Tags: c#, java, .net, sha1

I am computing hash in my .net and Java application.But I got a problem when they gave me result because both are giving different results.While searching about this problem, I found these questions 
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205066/different-sha1-hash-result-between-java-and-c-sharp) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780261/hmc-sha1-hash-java-producing-different-hash-output-than-c-sharp) so applied there according tho their answers but unfortunately i didn't get success.I also tried `UTF-8` and `UTF-16LE` but result was again not same.

Now I am stuck and want to know why it is happening and **How can I solve this**
My code snippet is given below
**.Net**

```
byte[] buffer2 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(bytes);
```

**Java**

```
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] buffer2 = sha1.digest(bytes);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in endianness?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843698/calculating-sha-1-hashes-in-java-and-c-sharp

Comment: what is the value of `bytes` in both cases?

Comment: No i didn't find that .. let me check

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov both have same bytes values ..

Comment: If they have the same values... how are they different?

Comment: @Learner - glad I could helped. Entered my comment as an answe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is that in C# byte is unsigned type, and in java it not.

This 2 codes works equally:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 10 };
        byte[] buffer2 = sha1.digest(bytes);
        for(byte b : buffer2){
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 10 };
        var buffer = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(bytes);
        foreach (var b in buffer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((sbyte)b); //attention to cast           
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So just to recap my comment as an answer.
See this: [Calculating SHA-1 hashes in Java and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843698/calculating-sha-1-hashes-in-java-and-c-sharp)
Basically - Java bytes are signed while C# bytes are not.
The internal representation of both results will be the same but printing them will yield different results unless you do proper conversions.